# Why am I Getting a Null Pointer Exception When I Retrieve Bundle Arguments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a fragment within `MyActivity`, passing it the data it needs to display. I'm currently trying to pack all the data in a bundle through the static method `newInstance()`

When I open the activity however, I get a Null Pointer Exception when I try and unpack the bundle in `onCreateView()`

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

This occurs on the first call to `getInt()` which leads me to believe `getArguments()` is returning a null bundle for some reason, and I can't reason why it would.

MyActivity.java

```
/* Create Status Bar fragment */
FragmentManager fragMngr = getSupportFragmentManager();
frag = (StatusBarFragment)fragMngr.findFragmentById(R.id.f_container2);
if (frag == null)
{
    frag = StatusBarFragment.newInstance(player.getMoney(),
                                         player.getHealth(),
                                         player.getEquipmentMass());
    fragMngr.beginTransaction().add(R.id.f_container2, frag).commit();
 }
```

StatusBarFragment.java

```
public class StatusBarFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String MONEY = "vg.my.citruscode.money";
    private static final String HEALTH = "vg.my.citruscode.health";
    private static final String EQUIPMENT_MASS = "vg.my.citruscode.equipmentMass";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status_bar, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        // Omitted methods which update UI Elements
        updateMoney(args.getInt(MONEY, 0)); // This line causes exception
        updateHealth(args.getDouble(HEALTH, 0.0));
        updateEquipmentMass(args.getDouble(EQUIPMENT_MASS, 0.0));

        return parentView;
    }

    public static StatusBarFragment newInstance(int money, double health, double equipmentMass)
    {
        StatusBarFragment frag = new StatusBarFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putInt(MONEY, money);
        args.putDouble(HEALTH, health);
        args.putDouble(EQUIPMENT_MASS, equipmentMass);

        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
}
```

Comment: just quick question are using using in layout fragment like using <fragment> something

Comment: you have a if condition which is checking if(frag == null) this may be the reason. The code is not going into if block and you may be inflating a new fragment somewhere which don't have bundle. Try to have debug and check if code is running for bundle setting.

Comment: That check is in case the frag has already been created. The error is happening when the frag is first created, originating inside the `StatusBarFragment` class, so even if there were an already created frag, that frag would have had to be created, and caused the exception.

Answer (score -2):

Strange approach. I think there is a missing connection  between args and the data. On newInstance() do this.MONEY = money and the other strings.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. The purpose of those strings is to uniquely identify the data being stored in the Bundle.

Comment: Yes, true. Still setting this.money = money should work. Simple java OOP logic. Also as far as I know bundle is to be used for intents when switching activities/fragments like below suggestion and here you pass data to bundle when you create the fragment. But anyway try with this.money approach.

Comment: No, `this.money = money` would not work. The newInstance method is static, and so is not associated with an instance of StatusBarFragment. `this` makes no sense in a static context.

Comment: It doesnt have to be static

Comment: If the method was not static then you're saying you would need to instantiate an instance of the class, and then call it through that. This misses the point of the method entirely.

Comment: Yes I am. If you're not allowed to change that you need a new way to link newInstance() return to StatusBarFragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179041/discussion-between-i-am-a-terrible-programmer-and-rei-koleci).